# What do the downward arrow in "Start the active scheme" button indicate while hover in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have noticed that the downward arrow appears only when the button is being hovered. What does the downward arrow indicate?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kqAx.png)

Comment: That means that if you _hold_ the mouse / cursor down on the button, a pop-down menu will appear.

Comment: However, "how do I use my Mac" is not a programming question, even if you happen to be asking about Xcode, so please don't clutter up SO with that sort of thing. AskDifferent would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click for a longer period of time, you will see the following options:

[image: Result]

You will see:

- Run (<kbd>⌘ R</kbd>)
- Test (<kbd>⌘ U</kbd>)
- Profile (<kbd>⌘ I</kbd>)
- Analyse (<kbd>⇧ ⌘ B</kbd>)

This is just another way to access the options in the `Product` menu.